# Syntax error on simple If Else

Tags: ti-basic

I get an error at the 'Else' on a TI-84 Plus.
I can't figure out why this doesn't work.

I'm writing a GCD program just as an exercise in programming a TI calculator.
It's recursive (or as recursive as TI-BASIC gets).

```
If B=0
Disp A
Else
C->B
B->remainder(A,B)
A->B
prgmGCD2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TI-Basic is often rather picky about the syntax of if statements.

There are three general formats for an If statement.

### Single Statement If

```
:If <boolean>
:<expression>
```

Note that `<expression>` consists of exactly one line of code.

### Multi Statement If

```
:If <boolean>
:Then
:<expresion>
:<expresion>
:End
```

As opposed to the first option, this option can contain any number of lines of code after the `If`.

### If Else

```
:If <boolean>
:Then
:<expresion>
:<expresion>
:Else
:<expresion>
:<expresion>
:End
```

As with the previous option, any number of statements can be put after the `If` and after the `Else`.

---

You are obviously trying to use an if else statement. The correct syntax for this is:

```
:If B
:Then
:C->B
:B->remainder(A,B)
:A->B
:prgmGCD2
:Else
:Disp A
:End
```